# Solr function query "Unknown function lt in FunctionQuery('if(lt(9,2),1,0)'"

Tags: solr, solrj

> if(lt(9,2),1,0)

This should return 1. But instead it produce the error:

> Error parsing fieldname: Unknown function lt in FunctionQuery('if(lt(9,2),1,0)', pos=6)

This `if(true,1,0)` produce 1 correctly. `if(false,1,0)` produce 0 correctly.

`if(lt(9,2),1,0)`, `if(gt(9,2),1,0)` etc. do not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is self-explaining:

> Error parsing fieldname: **Unknown function lt** in
>   FunctionQuery('if(**lt**(9,2),1,0)', pos=6)

Looking at the Solr [documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery), there isn't an lt function in solr. Please use one of the available [functions](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) or the existing operators along with the if.

Comment: According to the 6.5 documentation yes there are boolean functions:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Function+Queries